# time format identification and convertion

Tags: c#, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

so I was trying to scrape a website which I came across a some sort of time thing

```
596842289558184
```

this the time format that my target website uses? Does anyone know what is this format?

Comment: It's likely the number of seconds or microsecond, or nanoseconds, or ticks from some epoch.  Maybe Jan 1st 1970 or maybe Jan 1 of the year 1.  Hard to tell for sure without context.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this time [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

It seems this number represents `Tuesday, 29 November 1988 21:31:29.558`